# How to prevent automatic simplification in InputField?

Tags: dynamic, inputfield, hold

Here is a basic example:

```
{InputField[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x]}
```

This code generates an input box with and dynamic display.
[image]

What is disturbing me is that when trying to enter some complex expressions, MMA automatically calculates and updates it in the input box. Is there any way to keep the expression in the input box remains unevaluated?

e.g. If I enter Exp[2.1]:

[image]

after I clicked somewhere else, the content of the input box turns into the result immediately, but I want the result to be displayed only beside the input box.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
{InputField[Dynamic[x], Hold[Expression]], Dynamic[ReleaseHold[x]]}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Many thanks! This works!